# Rearranging List with DisclosureGroups in edit mode

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to rearrange `List` rows when in edit mode.

Quick summary: I want `DisclosureGroup` rows like `Second` to not be inserted into their own children's hierarchy. It's fine if they go into any other hierarchy/level.

Below is some example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 1) { _ in
                DisclosureGroup("First", isExpanded: .constant(true)) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 1) { _ in
                        Text("Item 1")
                        Text("Item 2")

                        DisclosureGroup("Second", isExpanded: .constant(true)) {
                            // Individual
                            Text("Item 3")
                            Text("Item 4")

                            // Grouped
//                            ForEach(0 ..< 1) { _ in
//                                Text("Item 3")
//                                Text("Item 4")
//                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onMove(perform: { _, _ in })
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
        .environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
    }
}
```

This is what the line comments mean:

- **Individual**: this will allow the rows to move freely within the current level, but also means the `DisclosureGroup` row can move between these elements (not wanted)
- **Grouped**: this will 'lock' these views into this level of the hierarchy. For example `Item 3` and `Item 4` can be swapped rows, however these rows can no longer be dragged somewhere else such as between `Item 1` and `Item 2`.

When a `DisclosureGroup` row is dragged, either:

1. **All** the children should be dragged along with it.
2. This `DisclosureGroup` row should not be inserted between any of its own children.

We are purely focusing on visual UI for now, hence why the `onMove(perform:)` method is not completed.

| Individual method | Grouped method |
| --- | --- |
| [image: individual] | [image: grouped] |

Notes:

- **Individual method**: The `Second` row can be moved to the same layer as `Item 3` and `Item 4`, which should not be allowed. However, it does allow `Item 3` and `Item 4` to be between `Item 1` and `Item 2`.
- **Grouped method**: `Item 3` and `Item 4` are 'locked' into their own level - no views can be inserted between, nor can they move to the same level as `Item 1` and `Item 2` (bad). However, in this case `Second` cannot move into its own children's hierarchy (good).

How can I fix this, so I basically have the 'individual method', but `DisclosureGroup` rows like `Second` cannot be inserted into their own children's hierarchy? It's fine if they go into any other hierarchy/level.

I realise this is quite a complex question - so try the code for yourself and watch the GIFs to understand.

If it functions correctly, I'll accept a UIKit solution too (such as with `UICollectionView`?).

Comment: @MihaiFratu Nope, sorry - I still am looking for a solution too.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, `.onMove` does not currently work with nested ForEach. I've been working on [this](https://github.com/FlamedDogo99/BuggyNestedLists) as well, and the only thing I've found is flattening the array, and writing functions for handling the movement of nested items:

[image: Flattened List Gif].