# SwiftUI drag and droppable cells of horizontal list inside of a cell of a vertical list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get a drag an droppable horizontal list in cell view of a main list which vertical.

here is my solution. it doesnt work inside a cell view of a list view but it works outside of List{}. how to get a horizontal list to be drag and droppable for rearranging cells inside a cell of a Vertical List{}?

this is the main list view which show some cells with sections. i removed all other except the one with a cell containg horizontal list with drag and droppable of this sub list.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChipModel : Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let id : UUID
    var isSelected : Bool
    var titleKey : String
    var systemImage : String
}


struct AppView : View {


var myList = [ChipModel(id: UUID(), isSelected: false, titleKey: "Year", systemImage: ""), 
                    ChipModel(id: UUID(), isSelected: false, titleKey: "Month", systemImage: ""),
                    ChipModel(id: UUID(), isSelected: false, titleKey: "Day", systemImage: "")]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                
                    Section(header: Text("doc")) {
                        HStack {
                            ChipView(chips: myList)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the chipview

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers



struct ChipView : View {
    
    @State var chips : [ChipModel]
    @State var draggedItem: ChipModel?
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack(spacing : 5) {
            ForEach(chips, id:\.id.uuidString) { item in
                Text(item.titleKey)
                    .frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth:.infinity, minHeight:50)
                    .border(Color.black).background(Color.red)
                    .onDrag({
                        self.draggedItem = item
                        return NSItemProvider(item: nil, typeIdentifier: item.id.uuidString)
                    }) .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: MyDropDelegate(item: item, items: $chips, draggedItem: $draggedItem))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyDropDelegate : DropDelegate {

    let item : ChipModel
    @Binding var items : [ChipModel]
    @Binding var draggedItem : ChipModel?

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        guard let draggedItem = self.draggedItem else {
            return
        }

        if draggedItem != item {
            let from = items.firstIndex(of: draggedItem)!
            let to = items.firstIndex(of: item)!
            withAnimation(.default) {
                self.items.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: from), toOffset: to > from ? to + 1 : to)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730367
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74669373/swiftui-move-rows-in-nested-foreach

Please refer to these pages. I believe there is a bug that hasn't been fixed yet.